# Write unicode text into HTML in python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to write unicode text into an HTML file in python 3. I've done the following:

```
with open('korean.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write("한국")
```

But it's failed, showing the garbage output:

```
í•œêµ­
```

It's clear there's some encoding issue going on here but I haven't been able to find a clear solution for some time now.

FYI, if I try the following, changing the file extension from .html to .txt

```
with open('korean.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("한국")
```

This works as intended, showing the correctly coded korean text. So there's some issue that occurs when the file thats being saved to is an html extension.

Comment: <meta charset='utf-8'> is set ?

Comment: The `html` version is working by me. In text editor and in firefox.

Comment: @politinsa setting that solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Python script is doing exactly what you are asking it to do. Whatever you are using to examine the resulting file isn't. For more information about this, see the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your browser is unable to render correct characters. Try to read .html file on console. You should see right output.

Can you mention browser and version ?

Works for me in
python 3.7
Browser : Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
[html_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSMFl.png)